# $\gcd(a,n)=d$ and $s,t$ solutions to $ax\equiv b \pmod{n}$ then $s\equiv t\pmod{n/d}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> If $\gcd(a,n)=d$ and $s,t$ are each solutions to $ax\equiv b\pmod{n}$ then $s\equiv t \pmod{n/d}$.

As $d\mid a$ say $a=dm$ and as $s,t$ are each solutions, $as\equiv at\pmod{n}$ so
$$a(s-t)=nk \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}\\ \Rightarrow s-t=(nk)/a\\ \Rightarrow s-t=\frac{n}{d}\cdot\frac{k}{m}.$$

How can I show that $m\mid k$ so then $k/m\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do: $$as \equiv at \pmod n \implies \frac{a}{d}s \equiv \frac{a}{d}t \pmod {\frac{n}{d}} \implies \frac{n}{d}\mid\frac{a}{d}(s-t) \implies \frac{n}{d} \mid s-t,$$ the last implication because $\gcd\left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{n}{d}\right)=1$.

Comment: Okay I think your notation is "backwards" from what I am used to. I use $a \mid b$ to mean there exists integer $k$ such that $b=ak$ but it looks like to you, $a\mid b$ means exists integer $k$ such that $a=bk$.

Comment: $a\mid b$ means that exists $k \in \Bbb Z$ s.t. $b=ak$. Why do you think my notation is backwards? In fact, I didn't use that definition of $\mid$ directly anywhere..

Comment: I learned $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ if and only if $n\mid (a-b)$. You say $\frac{a}{d}s \equiv \frac{a}{d}t \pmod {\frac{n}{d}} \Rightarrow \frac{a}{d}(s-t) \mid \frac{n}{d}$ but I would think that it implies $\frac{n}{d} \mid \frac{a}{d}(s-t)$.

Comment: For the last part it looks like you are using if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid c$. But you say $\frac{a}{d}(s-t) \mid \frac{n}{d}$ implies $(s-t)\mid \frac{n}{d}$. If you are using $\mid$ like I have been then $ab \mid n$ means $b\mid n$ regardless of $\gcd(a,n)$, so it makes me think your $\mid$ is backwards. Basically to be consistent, it looked like your $\mid$ is backwards.

Comment: Oh, I saw it now. You are correct. I'm sorry, I should have payed more attention. Please check my edit, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, there exists some integer $k$ such that
$$a(s-t)=nk$$
Therefore
$$\frac ad(s-t)=k\frac nd$$

Since $a/d$ is integer, $s-t$ divides $n/d$.